# Https laravel locale

Tags: laravel, http, telegram-bot, https, бот

обучаюсь разработке Ботов.На данные момент использую BotMan и хочу связать его с telegram. Как разрабатывать бота локально если требуется https?Я использую в качестве сервера MAMP (macOS).Благодарю за любую информацию.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) или [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.github.io/www/) для вывода вашего localhost в интернет.
Я использовал оба варианта для аналогичных целей.
Ngrok предоставит вам на выбор две ссылки: http и https, а Localtunnel сразу создаст https.
По личным наблюдениям localtunnel немного стабильнее, но задачу свою они выполняют оба.